# XSLT to copy element without namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'll firstly qualify that I'm not particularly good at XSLT. But what I'm trying to do is to copy 3 XML documents into one parent document.

The XSLT works fine, except that the parent nodes are being printed with xmlns="" attribute which is causing my validations to fail.

So my question is how do I copy these elements out from the separate documents without it adding that xmlns attribute?

This is sample of the output to the destination - note I want it to not print the xmlns="".

```
<Feed xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/5.6"
name="Officeworks" incremental="false"
extractDate="2014-01-28T14:42:12+11:00">
  <Brands xmlns="">
    <Brand>
      <Name>Panasonic</Name>
      <ExternalId>12345</ExternalId>
    </Brand>
```

This is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ex="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="ex"> 

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="dateNow" select="ex:date-time()"/>
  <Feed xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/5.6" name='Officeworks' incremental='false'>
  <xsl:attribute name="extractDate"><xsl:value-of select="$dateNow" /></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('@dataload.bv.xml.out.tmp@/bv_brands_xml.001.xml')/Brands"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('@dataload.bv.xml.out.tmp@/bv_categories_xml.001.xml')/Categories"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('@dataload.bv.xml.out.tmp@/bv_products_xml.001.xml')/Products"/>
  </Feed>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your information is very confusing. You are explicitly creating the Feed element in namespace "http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/5.6", and in response to keshlam you say the nodes are supposed to be in that namespace, but then you say you do not want it "to print the xmlns=... attribute" which is the thing that puts it in that namespace. Do you want it in a namespace or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xmlns=""` is required because you're asserting a default namespace (with `xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/5.6"`) and then outputting nodes which are not in that namespace. For XML to represent that properly, it has to cancel the default namespace.

You haven't told us how validation is failing. If it's failing because those nodes should be in the specified namespace, they need to either be in that namespace before you copy them, or you need to replace the `xsl:copy-of` operation with one that explicitly reconstructs them by extracting their localname and using that and the desired namespace as parameters of an `xsl:element` operation. The items listed at right under **Related** will tell you more about this.

Comment: The nodes are supposed to be in that namespace. I do have access to the source routine so potentially I can modify it to put them into that namespace. I'll try that.

Comment: That'd certainly be the easiest solution. Namespaces are part of the name of the node. Leaving them out when generating the document is like leaving out a letter from the name -- it changes the document's meaning. You can fix it up, but better to "spell" it correctly in the first place if you can do so.

Comment: I ended up giving up trying to put the source nodes into the namespace. The nodes were printing with the right namespace in the source files, but then when the xslt ran it wasn't copying them into the file. I'm sure it's just me not understanding xslt properly. So I fell back to the local copy approach and just explicitly setting them into the right namespace, that seems to have resolved the issue so it will do for a solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="bla" copy-namespaces="no"></xsl:copy-of>
```

sorry...just noticed you are using XSLT 1, so copy-namespaces is not supported...my bad

Comment: not by any particular choice, it just seems to be what ANT support by default (which is what I'm using to run the xslt transformations amongst other things). I've hit a few issues where it would have been easily solved with XSLT 2.