# XSLT copy node without namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

(XML version="1.0") I'm quite new to XSLT. I have been given the the following XML:

```
<SNAPSHOTS>
  <SNAPSHOT>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <STATUS>COM</STATUS>
  </SNAPSHOT>
  <SNAPSHOT>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <STATUS>ACC</STATUS>
  </SNAPSHOT>
</SNAPSHOTS>
```

As of my requirements I've managed to transformed the provided XML to be contained within a `<DC>` root element and include a header before the `<SNAPSHOTS>` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DC>
  <Header>
    <FileName>TEST.xml</FileName>
    <NoOfRecords>2</NoOfRecords>
  </Header>

  <SNAPSHOTS>
    <SNAPSHOT>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <STATUS>COM</STATUS>
    </SNAPSHOT>
    <SNAPSHOT>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <STATUS>ACC</STATUS>
    </SNAPSHOT>
  </SNAPSHOTS>
<DC>
```

This is the XSD I've created:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <DC>
         <Header>
            <FileName>TEST.xml</FileName>
            <NoOfRecords><xsl:value-of select="count(SNAPSHOTS/SNAPSHOT)"/></NoOfRecords>
         </Header>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </DC>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()" name="removeNode">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I include **namespaces** into the `<DC>` the namespace gets copied to the  node also.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <DC xmlns="http://TEST/TEST.xsd"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> <<-- NAMESPACE ADDED
             <Header>
                <FileName>TEST.xml</FileName>
                <NoOfRecords><xsl:value-of select="count(SNAPSHOTS/SNAPSHOT)"/></NoOfRecords>
             </Header>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </DC>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DC xmlns="http://TEST/TEST.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Header>
    <FileName>TEST.xml</FileName>
    <NoOfRecords>2</NoOfRecords>
  </Header>

  <SNAPSHOTS xmlns="">    <<--INCORRECT
    <SNAPSHOT>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <STATUS>COM</STATUS>
    </SNAPSHOT>
    <SNAPSHOT>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <STATUS>ACC</STATUS>
    </SNAPSHOT>
  </SNAPSHOTS>
<DC>
```

I've tried many solutions (Googling 'XSLT copy node without namespace' etc.). One of the way's I've tried is the following ([xsl copy nodes without xmlns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998180/xsl-copy-nodes-without-xmlns)) but It does not remove the xmlns=""

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"  mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I've also read the following but don't fully understand the accepted answer.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397126/xslt-to-copy-element-without-namespace)

I have been working on this for hours and there is obviously something I just don't get. I sorry if I'm missing something simple considering similar questions have been asked before!! Many thanks your any help you can provide! Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your input XML, the `SNAPSHOTS` node, and all descendant nodes, are not part of any namespace. In your XSLT, you are adding a default namespace to `DC`, but you then copy the `SNAPSHOTS` from the input which has no namespace, so the `xmlns=''` has to be added to show the `SNAPSHOTS` is not in any namespace. Without it, it would mean `SNAPSHOTS` was part of the default namespace you added for `DC`.

Now, assuming you want your output like this:

```
<DC xmlns="http://TEST/TEST.xsd">
  <Header>
    <FileName>TEST.xml</FileName>
    <NoOfRecords>2</NoOfRecords>
  </Header>
  <SNAPSHOTS>
    <SNAPSHOT>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <STATUS>COM</STATUS>
    </SNAPSHOT>
    <SNAPSHOT>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <STATUS>ACC</STATUS>
    </SNAPSHOT>
  </SNAPSHOTS>
</DC>
```

Then, instead of copying the `SNAPSHOTS` nodes as-is, you create new nodes with the same local-name, but which are part of the same namespace.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <DC xmlns="http://TEST/TEST.xsd">
         <Header>
            <FileName>TEST.xml</FileName>
            <NoOfRecords><xsl:value-of select="count(SNAPSHOTS/SNAPSHOT)"/></NoOfRecords>
         </Header>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </DC>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="*" name="removeNode">
         <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://TEST/TEST.xsd">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
         </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that `SNAPSHOTS` is now part of the `http://TEST/TEST.xsd` and so not the same as the `SNAPSHOTS` in the input, which is not part of a namespace.

On the otherhand, perhaps `SNAPSHOTS` should not be part of a namespace? In this case, you could try using namespace prefixes, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <t:DC xmlns:t="http://TEST/TEST.xsd">
         <t:Header>
            <t:FileName>TEST.xml</t:FileName>
            <t:NoOfRecords><xsl:value-of select="count(SNAPSHOTS/SNAPSHOT)"/></t:NoOfRecords>
         </t:Header>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </t:DC>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="node()" name="removeNode">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output the following

```
<t:DC xmlns:t="http://TEST/TEST.xsd">
   <t:Header>
      <t:FileName>TEST.xml</t:FileName>
      <t:NoOfRecords>2</t:NoOfRecords>
   </t:Header>
   <SNAPSHOTS>
      <SNAPSHOT>
         <ID>1</ID>
         <STATUS>COM</STATUS>
      </SNAPSHOT>
      <SNAPSHOT>
         <ID>2</ID>
         <STATUS>ACC</STATUS>
      </SNAPSHOT>
   </SNAPSHOTS>
</t:DC>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the following: You declare a default namespace on one output element (`DC`, a newly created element), but not on the elements inside it (`SNAPSHOT` and so on, which are retrieved from the input XML). The XSLT processor is forced to assume that you meant to say that those elements inside  are *not* in this default namespace.

If you also declare the same default namespace on the remainder of the elements from the input XML:

```
<xsl:template match="*" name="removeNode">
   <xsl:element name="{name()}" xmlns="http://TEST/TEST.xsd">
```

the namespace undeclaration disappears. To me, it is still unclear *why* you need to declare those two namespaces on the `DC` element.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <DC xmlns="http://TEST/TEST.xsd"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <Header>
            <FileName>TEST.xml</FileName>
            <NoOfRecords><xsl:value-of select="count(SNAPSHOTS/SNAPSHOT)"/></NoOfRecords>
         </Header>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </DC>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="*" name="removeNode">
         <xsl:element name="{name()}" xmlns="http://TEST/TEST.xsd">
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DC xmlns="http://TEST/TEST.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Header>
      <FileName>TEST.xml</FileName>
      <NoOfRecords>2</NoOfRecords>
   </Header>
   <SNAPSHOTS>
      <SNAPSHOT>
         <ID>1</ID>
         <STATUS>COM</STATUS>
      </SNAPSHOT>
      <SNAPSHOT>
         <ID>2</ID>
         <STATUS>ACC</STATUS>
      </SNAPSHOT>
   </SNAPSHOTS>
</DC>
```