# Copy xml elements without namespace

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a XML file which contains html elements. I want copy them without have the namespaces being copied.

```xml
<clonkDoc xmlns="https://clonkspot.org"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="https://clonkspot.org clonk.xsd" xml:lang="de">
    <doc>
        foo <br/> bar
    </doc>
</clonkDoc>
```

and this XSL (truncated):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="https://clonkspot.org" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"/>

    <xsl:template match="img|a|em|strong|br|code/i|code/b">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <!-- including every attribute -->
            <xsl:for-each select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
...
```

i get something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        foo <br xmlns="https://clonkspot.org"></br> bar
    </body>
</html>
```

I already set `copy-namespaces="no"` ([XSLT to copy element without namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397126/xslt-to-copy-element-without-namespace)). I think the XSLT processor should see that the element i want to copy to a HTML4 file is an html element. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`xsl:copy` in all version of XSLT makes a shallow copy of the context node and in case of an element (or other node with a qualified name like an attribute node) node that means a copy with the same name **and** namespace. The `copy-namespaces="no"` introduced in XSLT 2 only helps to avoid to also copy in scope namespace declarations that exist but are not used for the element itself.

So in your case, as you want to strip the existing namespace of the elements, you really want to and need to transform them with a template doing that e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="img|a|em|strong|br|code/i|code/b">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">...</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Based on your solution i solved it with:

```xml
    <!-- copy img, a, em and br literally -->
    <xsl:template match="img|a|em|strong|br|code/i|code/b">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <!-- including every attribute -->
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

That should work recursively and take the attributes with.

Comment: Why `<xsl:for-each select="node()"><xsl:apply-templates select="."/></xsl:for-each>` and not simply `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` (which can further shortened to `<xsl:apply-templates/>`)?

Comment: I was not sure if that would be recursive, but i'll try it out!